# Approximation of a non-trivial gaussian integral

Tags: integration, limits, taylor-expansion, approximation, gaussian-integral

I want to show that the following integral is $O(T)$ for $T\rightarrow0$

$$ \int_0^{+\infty}dz\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}e^{-\frac{2z}{T}\,\sqrt{q(T)}}$$

where $q(T)=1-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}T+O(T^2)$. I tried with the expansion of $e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}$ inside the integral and then reconstructing the integral representation of the Euler Gamma function, but I'm not convinced it is the right thing to do. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the integral be $f(T)$. Then, substituting $z=\frac{Tx}{2\sqrt{q(T)}}$, you get (by [DCT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem)) $$\frac{f(T)}{T}=\frac1{2\sqrt{2\pi q(T)}}\int_0^\infty\exp\left(-x-\frac{T^2 x^2}{8q(T)}\right)dx\color{blue}{\underset{T\to 0}{\longrightarrow}}\frac1{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\color{lightgray}{\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\,dx}.$$

Comment: How did you use the DCT in this case? Are you considering the limit of $f(T)$ as the limit of a sequence? However thank you, it is simple and direct!

Comment: @saveriopalazzi: [sequences suffice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#In_terms_of_sequences) *(broadly)*.

Answer (score 2):

$$q(T)=1-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} T+O\left(T^2\right)$$
$$\sqrt{q(T)}=1-\frac{T}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}+O\left(T^2\right)$$ Completing the square, for any $T$ positive and smaller than $2\pi$
$$I=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}e^{-\frac{2z}{T}\,\sqrt{q(T)}}\,dz$$
$$I=\frac 12 \exp\left( \frac{\left(T\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} -2\right)^2}{2 T^2}  \right)\left(1+\text{erf}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi
   }}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{T}\right)\right)$$ leading to the limit already provided by @metamorphy.